# Does this q-analogue have a nice closed form?

Tags: q-analogs

Let $[n]_q=1+q+\cdots+q^{n-1}$.  Is there a nice closed form of $\sum_{s=1}^i[s]_{q}$?   One would expect that the answer will be some q-analog of $\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$, since $\sum_{s=1}^i s=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$.

Also I'm quite unfamiliar with q-theory, so if my terminology/notation is imprecise please let me know!

Comment: [Alpha knows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bq%5Ek,+%7Bs,+1,+i%7D,+%7Bk,+0,+s+-+1%7D%5D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$[n]_q=\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$

$\Sigma_{s=1}^i\frac{q^s-1}{q-1}=\frac{(q-1)+(q^2-1)+...+(q^i-1)}{q-1}=\frac{1+q+q^2+...+q^i-(i+1)}{q-1}=\frac{q^{i+1}-1}{(q-1)^2}-\frac{i+1}{q-1}=\frac{[i+1]_q-(i+1)}{q-1}$